# Filter a Map object by its values without collecting the result into another map

Tags: java

As the question says. I am trying to find the best way to filter a map with streams, without using iterator / remove.
All the snippets that I found return a new map. That's not what i want. What I want is that the Map itself is filtered so I can use this same object.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how streams work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with streams, as per the comment. The closest you can do is something like this (fulfills 'same map' requirement, but fails 'with streams' one):

```
yourMap.entrySet().removeIf(k -> someRemovalCheck());
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't want to create a new `Map`, I'd recommend invoking [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) on [`Map#values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()).

This will work because `Map#values` returns a view of the `Map`'s values, and any modifications made to that view are reflected in the `Map`.

So, for example, you could use:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1, "One", 2, "Two", 3, "Three"));
System.out.println(map); 
map.values().removeIf("Three"::equals);
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
[2=Two, 1=One, 3=Three]
[1=One, 2=Two]
```